# Full expansion of $\det(I+\varepsilon A)$

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

It is well known that given a $n \times n$ matrix $A$, it holds that

$$ \det(I + \varepsilon A)= 1 + \varepsilon \operatorname{tr}(A) + O(\varepsilon ^2).$$

I would need a full representation of $ \det(I + \varepsilon A)$, or at least some bounds explicitly depending on $A$. The reason is that I have to deal with a matrix $A$ which will depend on $\varepsilon$, in particular its entries will have to tend to infinity as $\varepsilon \to 0$ while $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ stays bounded. The problem is that, a priori, higher order terms could mess up the estimate, so I need a more precise representation. A similar question was asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174639/series-expansion-of-the-determinant-for-a-matrix-near-the-identity, but without a source. According to the answerer, such formulas are well known by representation theorists (that's the reason of the tag), but he couldn't remember a reference.

Comment: If you write $I+\varepsilon A = \exp(B)$ then $\det(I+\varepsilon A) = \exp(\mathrm{Tr}(B))$. So just Taylor-expand $\log(I+\varepsilon A)$.

Comment: a nice formula $${\displaystyle \det(I+A)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{k!}}\left(-\sum _{j=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{j}}{j}}\operatorname {tr} \left(A^{j}\right)\right)^{k}\,,}$$ is here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Trace. The condition is that the absolute value of every eigenvalue of A is less than 1.

Comment: $\det(I + \epsilon A) = \epsilon^{n}\det(\epsilon^{-1}I+A) = \epsilon^{n} \chi_{-A}(\epsilon^{-1})$, so we get a polynomial with degree at most $n$.

Comment: I do not think anything useful can be obtained in such generality. E.g., suppose that the diagonal entries of $A$ are zero and the off-diagonal entries of $A$ are $\asymp1/\varepsilon$.

Comment: Not sure if it's of help (?) but there are some interesting historical comments at this question of mine in [MSE 277124](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277124/origin-and-use-of-an-identity-of-formal-power-series-det1-psi-t-exp) about such determinants.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$
The exact expansion is
$$\det(1+tA) = \sum t^i \sigma_i(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n),$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\sigma_i$ is the $i$-th elementary symmetric polynomial, e.g. $\sigma_0=1, \sigma_1=\sum \lambda_i, \sigma_2=\sum _{i\ne j}\lambda_i \lambda_j, \ldots$ These are the same coefficients as in the characteristic polynomial of $A$, but in reverse order (perhaps up to sign)

As pointed out in the comments, there are ways to get these coefficients from traces of powers of your matrix, if these are any easier to come by than the eigenvalues themselves; this is because $\tr(A^k)=\sum \lambda_i^k$ forms another basis (at least rationally) of the ring of symmetric polynomials in the $\lambda_i$, so one needs only to determine the base change coefficients between this basis and the one consisting of the $\sigma_i$.

([Newton's identitites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) are one explicit way to do this, there may be better)

Comment: I think this might settle it. $\sigma_1$ is the trace, while for the other $\sigma_i$s, I can bound the eigenvalues in terms of the $L^\infty$ norm of the matrix (Gershgoring theorem if I am not mistaken). If I make the entries of $A$ scale like, say, $\varepsilon ^{-1/2}$, the higher order terms in the sum scale as $\varepsilon$ or as $o (\varepsilon)$.

Comment: A question: the formula you provide holds in full generality, right? No hypothesis on triangulability of the matrix or something like that?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't require anything. The matrix should be square, otherwise this works in full generality, even over arbitrary coefficient fields. The proof is just multiplying $1+tA$ by $t^{-1}$ and noting that this matrix's determinant is, by definition, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ evaluated at $-t^{-1}$.